# Dictionary Key Sort Options - Alpha then Numeric

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

All,

I would like to sort this mutable dictionary of arrays keys like so: A-Z 0-9 but it's coming back sorted 0-9 A-Z. How can I sort it such that the alpha chars come before the numbers? Perhaps there is a built-in method that does this or should I create a category that extends NSString?

```
    NSArray *sKeysArray = [[listContent allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *sectionKey = [sKeysArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionValues = [listContent valueForKey:sectionKey];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly there's no method in `NSString` that will directly do this. Instead of writing a category, I would just use `NSArray`s `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method:

```
NSArray *sKeysArray = [[listContent ALlKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
// Code to compare obj1 and obj2 and return an NSComparisonResult here; return NSOrderedAscending if obj1 should come before obj2 
}];
```

To do each comparison, I would use `NSString`'s  `– enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` passing `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` for options (basically enumerating characters, except that unicode characters sequences which are actually one "letter" are combined). And when you're comparing two characters, use something like the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644004/how-to-check-if-nsstring-is-numeric) to detect when obj1 is a number and obj2 is regular letter and return `NSOrderedDescending`, otherwise just use regular `compare:`.

Answer (score 2):

Like @yuri says, `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` should provide the basic functionality.

Here is a simple version that sorts strings beginning with a decimal digit after strings beginning with an alphabetic character (in `NSCharacterSet`'s definition), and leaves all other combinations of strings to their default sort order:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"ABC 09 GHJ", @"DEF23PO", @"123ABC", @"MCMLXV", @"[cocoa]", @"$2000", @"ERT", @"24seven", @"zero",
                @"Ångström", @"Übernacht",
                nil];

NSCharacterSet *digits    = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *alphanums = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];

NSArray *sorted = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ( [obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [obj1 length] > 0
        && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [obj2 length] > 0 ) {

        unichar c1 = [obj1 characterAtIndex:0];
        unichar c2 = [obj2 characterAtIndex:0];

        if ( [digits characterIsMember:c1] && (![digits characterIsMember:c2] && [alphanums characterIsMember:c2]) ) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if ( [digits characterIsMember:c2] && (![digits characterIsMember:c1] && [alphanums characterIsMember:c1]) ) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
    }

    return [obj1 compare: obj2];
}];

NSLog(@"Sorted: %@", sorted);
```

Caveat: It will not handle a unicode letter composed of a decimal digit as the first component correctly, but I will consider that a pathological case until someone can enlighten me.