# compare:options: How to sort symbols before numbers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm currently using this compare options to sort a list of strings:

```
 [self compare:aString options:NSNumericSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

However, numbers come before than symbols:

```
99
[Hello
Hello
```

Is there a way to sort symbols before numbers ?
thanks

Comment: There should be some useful information in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327997/dictionary-key-sort-options-alpha-then-numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all symbols come before numbers in the ASCII table, which is why you noticed this behaviour with `'['`. Assuming `self` in your example is an `NSArray`, you'll need to use the [`sortedArrayUsingComparator:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a) method and implement a custom sorter. (Other classes besides `NSArray` will have this method as well.)

```
NSComparator sortBlock = ^(id string1, id string2)
{
    // Fill this in
};

NSArray* sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:sortBlock];
```

Check out [Getting Started with Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html) on Apple's developer site.